# bad scrolling Ubuntu 18.04 with Libre office 6.3

Tags: touchpad, scrolling

HP laptop scroll pad works fine in other applications.

Useless scolling in Libre Office 6.3 with Ubuntu 18.04 with Gnome.

Noticed question has been asked on other sites but not seen any recommendations for Libre Office. Any help welcome!

Comment: Recognize this. Scrolling for me works very well in evince and other apps, but les so in LO. Provide full system details because the graphical card and the driver you use can make a difference.

Comment: Yes it so with my other apps too. Intel CPU Ubuntu driver -Display-
Resolution  : 1366x768 pixels
Vendor  : The X.Org Foundation
Version  : 1.19.6
XVideo

Comment: Information relevant to solving a question should be added to the question: edit your question.

Comment: Hope the following helps: Further Info from lspci "Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)"  sudo lshw "broadcast=yes driver=ath9k driverversion=5.2.3-050203-generic"